# Edit Tierprice display

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce, magento-1.6

How to let that information tierprice, appear in the table, as shown in picture

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you kidding? How are we supposed to help with nothing but an image of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfect Gershon Herczeg,

I broke his head a little, but managed to solve.

In the "tierprice.phtml" located in / app / design / frontend / base / default / template / catalog / product / view changed the following lines.

Line 50 after the endif added to the "static" table

```
    <h4 class="tierprice"> Progressive Discount Table </ h4>
<li> <table> <td style="background:#dfdfdf;border:1px solid #b4b4b4;padding:4px;text-align:center;"> Qty. </ td> </ tr>
   <td style="border:1px solid #b4b4b4;padding:4px;text-align:center;">Price</ td> </ tr></ table> </ li>
```

And in line 185 after the else, added the following code

```
   <? php echo $ this-> __ ("<td <table> style="background:#dfdfdf;border:1px solid #b4b4b4;padding:4px;text-align:center;">% + $ 1 s units. </ tr> </ td> <td style="border:1px solid #b4b4b4;padding:4px;text-align:center;">% 2 $ s </ tr> </ td> </ table> ', $ _price ['price_qty'], $ _price ['formated_price'])?>
```

Thanks to those who helped, and for who is complaining that the response to and

Thanks Again

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some general direction:

1. Go to admin panel turn on template hints (http://vimeo.com/1067069)
2. Reload page and find the associated template file, it will probably be named something like tierprice.html or similar.
3. Change around the html to display as you like.

If you get a specific issue while you are doing this then would be a good time to post another question.

Comment: Sure thing, glad you figured it out.